# SQL Server - Compare two Rows, if match, than Pick row X

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables which look like this:

```
event_ap

Event   a_nr    tnr    date         timestamp    knr   maschnr
PAN        123     2203   2017-01-23   21600        11    x222
PAN        132     2203   2017-01-22   21600        22    x222
PAB        123     2203   2017-01-23   28523        11    x222
PAN        555     2203   2017-01-23   14023        33    x222
PAN        555     2201   2017-01-23   21235        44    x222
PAB        222     2202   2017-01-23   21245        44    x222
PAN        666     2202   2017-01-28   35000        44    x222
PAB        666     2202   2017-01-28   35000        44    x222

pers_stm

name  knr
Test1 11
Test2 22
Test3 33
Test4 44
```

So what I need is the last record for each ID (knr). My query for this looks like this

```
select *  
From ( 
      select * 
      from ( select *
                   , row_number() over (partition  by knr 
                                        order by date desc, timestamp desc) as RN 
             from event_ap 
            ) X 
      where RN = 1 
     ) Y 
join pers_stm p on p.knr = Y.knr
```

But there is an issue with this.

As you can see above in the example of the Table "event_ap" (**last two records**) there are records with the **exact same data** (including same timestamp) the only **difference** is the **Event-Tag**.

***So what i need based on the query i have so far:***

- (get the **last record** of table event_ap (**date, timestamp**) already accomplished with query above)
- if there are **two records with the same date, timestamp and ID (knr)** then p**ick the record with the event-Tag "PAN"** as query result

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `Event desc` into the `order by` clause of your `over (...)` so it becomes:

```
select *  
From ( 
      select * 
      from ( select *
               , row_number() over (partition  by knr 
                                    order by date desc, timestamp desc, Event desc) as RN 
             from event_ap 
            ) X 
      where RN = 1 
     ) Y 
join pers_stm p on p.knr = Y.knr
```

This does assume that you only have 'PAB' and 'PAN' in your Event column. If you have anything else in there that would be before 'PAN' in a descending text sort then Tim's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `case` expression to the row number partition *after* first ordering by `date` and `timestamp`:

```
case when Event = 'PAN' then 0 else 1 end
```

This will force `PAN` event records to the top should two or more records have the same date/timestamp.  In case where there is no tie for date/timestamp this `case` expression will have no effect, and in cases where there *is* a tie but no `PAN` records are present, it also won't have an effect.

```
select *
From
(
    select *
    from
    (
        select *,
               row_number() over
               (partition by knr order by date desc,
                                          timestamp desc,
                case when Event = 'PAN' then 0 else 1 end) as RN
        from event_ap
    ) X
    where RN = 1
) Y
join pers_stm p
    on p.knr = Y.knr
```